# Where to find GetMemberInfo

Tags: c#, wpf

I have looked up for this everywhere, I have downloading the `DLL` for the `LINQ Data` and also have add `System.Reflection` in the reference but it still cannot find it.

C# Code:

```
protected void NotifyOfPropertyChanged(string name)
{
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
}

protected void NotifyOfPropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
{
      NotifyOfPropertyChanged(property.GetMemberInfo().Name);
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
NotifyOfPropertyChanged(property.GetMemberInfo().Name);
```

And the error reads:

```
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TProperty>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetMemberInfo' and no extension method 'GetMemberInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TProperty>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(this Expression expression)
{
    var lambda = (LambdaExpression)expression;

    MemberExpression memberExpression;
    if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
    {
        var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
        memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
    }
    else
        memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;

    return memberExpression.Member;
}
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain how do you put anything in there that's not a `LambdaExpression`? I mean, how can this method be used on anything else?

Comment: @user3157821 *"this doesn't work"* is really vague and unspecific. Can you please clarify. do you get an exception? if so, what is it? it works in my Framework.

Comment: @HighCore Sorry, Hmm the error is exactly the same nothing changed.

Comment: @user3157821 you need to put this `Extension Method` in a static class, and use that via a `using` directive.