# GetMemberInfo not found when using .NET 4.5.2

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, .net-4.5.2

I was using this code in a library project using the Framework .NET 4.5 and it works fine

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)
{
    if (this.IsInpcActive)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(property.GetMemberInfo().Name);
    }
}
```

I copy-pasted this code in a project using the .NET Frameworkwith 4.5.2 and I receive this error message:

```
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TProperty>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetMemberInfo' and no extension method 'GetMemberInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TProperty>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

As I don't really want to loose too much time, I found a plan B: extension method:

```
internal static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    #region Methods

    public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(this Expression expression)
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)expression;

        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        }
        else
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;

        return memberExpression.Member;
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

But I'm cusious: **where did this method go?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find GetMemberInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955547/where-to-find-getmemberinfo)

Comment: @Nikolai no, that's where OP got this code.

Comment: @CodeCaster actually it is a duplicate - there is no such method so a new one must be created. It's just happened that the OP included the duplicate's answer in the question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _"there is no such method so a new one must be created"_ - and that is not **explained** in that other question, so that is not a duplicate. Sure, it contains code that when copy-pasted solves OP's _problem_, but that is not their _question_, as they found that solution themselves already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Expression<TDelegate>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx) has no method `GetMemberInfo()`, and it never had. So your problem seems to lie here:

> I copy-pasted this code in a project

So to me it looks like your version compiled against 4.5 used the same or an equivalent extension method, otherwise it wouldn't have compiled.

See for example [this one from the Enterprise Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn134408(v=pandp.60).aspx):

> `StaticReflection.GetMemberInfo<T, TProperty>` Method
>
> Retrieves a PropertyInfo object for the set method from an expression in the form x => x.SomeProperty.

So your original code should have this at the top:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Utility;
```

And a reference to the Enterprise Library.

Comment: Indeed, I over looked the `(extension)` displayed in the tooltip when I hover the property with the mouse...